# Troubles installing Facbeook SDK for Python

Tags: python, facebook, import, module

I have downloaded the Facebook SDK from:

> https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/

In my Python install folder, I created a folder called fb and extracted the files from GitHub into this folder. I then ran:

> setup.py install

To install the module. However, when I try and run

> from facebook import Facebook

in the Python Shell I get the following:

> >>> from facebook import Facebook
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File pyshell#0, line 1, in 
>      from facebook import Facebook
>   ImportError: cannot import name Facebook

However when I simply write from facebook import *, I receive no errors.

What step haven't I taken to get this working correctly? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any examples of the code you are trying to run/emulate? I'm sure we can get something figured out.

Comment: Install it using ' sudo pip install facebook-sdk ' instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're doing everything correctly - your problem is that there isn't a `Facebook` object inside of the `facebook` module (see the code [here](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook.py)). The reason the `*` import works is because that is the syntax to import all names. From your code, you should be able to simply use `facebook.<your_method>` to call what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sdk, this is simpler and easy to use and has got detailed doc to help beginners
[Facebook python sdk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fb/0.3.0)